# Showing that a group with transposition acting transitively on ${1, \dots, n}$ is $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove that a group is $S_n$ where $n$ is any integer.

Right now I have gotten that it acts transitively on $\{1, \dots, n\}$, and contains a transposition.

Can I conclude from this that it is $S_n$? I think I'm missing something, but I can't find anything else about the group.

Comment: No this is not enough: $\langle (13),(1234) \rangle = D_4 \neq S_4$, though this group acts transitively and contains a transposition. Can you give more context?

Answer (score 1):

Like MooS said, it is not enough. I sum up some conditions that imply that a permutation group $H$ is $S_n$.

1. If $n$ is prime, $H$ contains a transposition and acts transitively on $\{1,\dots,n\}$.
2. If $n$ is an integer, $H$ contains a transposition and acts doubly transitively on $\{1,\dots,n\}$.
3. If $n$ is an integer, $H$ contains a transposition and a $(n-1)$-cycle.

Comment: How do you prove 2?

Comment: @Daniele1234 If $H$ is doubly transitive, then WLOG let $(12)$ is in $H$, then by doubly transitivity, for any $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$, $(m\ n)$ is in $H$ too.  This gives all transposition in $H$ and thus $H=S_n$